# Not able to find FragmentStackSupport class in android samples

Tags: android, android-fragments

I wanted to try `FragmentTabHost` as explained in [developers docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/TabActivity.html)

The example is using a class `FragmentStackSupport` class, which I guessed should be present in google samples.

Then I downloaded samples of various verions but still not able to find this class.

If I'm doing something wrong please advice.

One more issue I've seen is every download link goes to same page, like:

http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentStackSupport.html

goes to http://developer.android.com/tools/samples/index.html